# Hessian of a function of matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, tensors, hessian-matrix

I'm asking again some help with Matrix calculus.

I am interested in computing the Hessian of a function of matrices, namely:
$$f(\Sigma) = \log\left(1 + y^\top\Sigma^{-1}y\right)$$ with $y$ a constant vector and $\Sigma$ a symmetric positive definite matrix.

I can compute the gradient as
$$ G = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma} = \frac{\Sigma^{-1}yy^\top\Sigma^{-1}}{1+y^\top\Sigma^{-1}y}$$
but then I am stuck with the Hessian.

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450629/hessian-of-matrix-fractional-function) question, but the proposed function is simpler and in that case I am able to find an answer (I will post there when I get some time). In the meantime, following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3453501/729550) answer I managed to find 
$$ dG = \frac{-\Sigma^{-1} d\Sigma \Sigma^{-1} (yy^\top) \Sigma^{-1} - \Sigma^{-1} (yy^\top) \Sigma^{-1} d\Sigma \Sigma^{-1}}{1+y^\top\Sigma^{-1}y} + X $$
but $X$ is still a mistery for me.

By applying the product rule, $X$ should be the derivative of the denominator times the numerator and divided by the denominator squared. But what is supposed to come out of this? I would expect a symmetric tensor (of course), but following my first instinct I get
$$ X = \frac{\Sigma^{-1}yy^\top\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma^{-1}yy^\top\Sigma^{-1}}{\left(1+y^\top\Sigma^{-1}y\right)^2}\Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma\Sigma^{-1} $$
and this term is a correct second order tensor (the part with $\Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma\Sigma^{-1}$) but has a matrix coefficient, it appears. What to do with it? I firstly thought of contracting it with the first index of the first $\Sigma^{-1}$, but in doing this I am losing the symmetry of the Hessian.

I am not sure how to work in index notation, too, but I supposed that maybe the two parts that compose the numerator should contract with themselves, but I am throwing in the dark here, as I don't get why this should happen. I must confess that I am a bit lost in the notation here...

I tried [this](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) handy tool, but of course it does not work for fourth order tensors.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\eqalign{
e^f &= 1+y^T\Sigma^{-1}y \\
&= 1+yy^T:\Sigma^{-1} \\
&= 1+Y:\Sigma^{-1} \\
}$$
The differential is
$$\eqalign{
 de^f
 &= -Y:\Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma\,\Sigma^{-1} \\
e^fdf &= -\Sigma^{-1}Y\Sigma^{-1}:d\Sigma \\
G &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\Sigma}  = -e^{-f}\Sigma^{-1}Y\Sigma^{-1} \\
\\
dG
 &=
  -de^{-f}\Sigma^{-1}Y\Sigma^{-1}
  -e^{-f}d\Sigma^{-1}Y\Sigma^{-1}
  -e^{-f}\Sigma^{-1}Yd\Sigma^{-1} \\
 &=
  e^{-f}(df)\Sigma^{-1}Y\Sigma^{-1}
  +e^{-f}\Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma\,\Sigma^{-1}Y\Sigma^{-1}
  +e^{-f}\Sigma^{-1}Y\Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma\,\Sigma^{-1} \\
 &= -G(G:d\Sigma) - \Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma\,G - G\,d\Sigma\,\Sigma^{-1} \\
}$$
Vectorize the matrix terms
$$\eqalign{
s&=\operatorname{vec}(\Sigma),\quad \Sigma=\operatorname{Mat}(s) \\
g&=\operatorname{vec}(G),\quad G=\operatorname{Mat}(g)  \\
}$$
and write the equation as 
$$\eqalign{
dg &= -gg^Tds -(G\otimes\Sigma^{-1})ds -(\Sigma^{-1}\otimes G)ds \\
H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} 
 &= -gg^T - (G\otimes\Sigma^{-1}) - (\Sigma^{-1}\otimes G) \\
dg &= H\,ds,\qquad dG = \operatorname{Mat}(H\,ds) \\
}$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, and a colon represents the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)
}$$
The Hessian has been calculated as the matrix $H$.

If required, the components of the fourth-order Hessian tensor ${\cal H}$ can be calculated as follows.
$$\eqalign{
G_{ij} &= e_ie_j^T:G \\&= {\rm vec}(e_ie_j^T):g \\&= (e_j\otimes e_i):g \\
\\
\Sigma_{kl} &= (e_l\otimes e_k):s \\
\\
{\cal H}_{ijkl}
&= \frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial \Sigma_{kl}} \\
&= (e_j\otimes e_i)(e_l\otimes e_k)^T:\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\right)\\
&= (e_j\otimes e_i)(e_l\otimes e_k)^T:H \\
}$$
where the $\{e_k\}$ are the standard basis vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much! Referring to the notation of your answer on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3453501/729550), can I write the Hessian as:
$ H = - G \mathcal{E} G - \Sigma^{-1}\mathcal{E}G - G\mathcal{E}\Sigma^{-1} $ where $\mathcal{E}$ is the identity for the exchange of both index $i\to k$ and $j\to l$?

Comment: Not quite. The first term needs to be changed from $G{\cal E}G$ to the dyadic product $G\star G$, whose components are $(G\star G)_{ijkl}=G_{ij}G_{kl}$